# Exclude project from Find Symbols / Find All References

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want Visual Studio to search for symbols / references in specified projects only. How can I achieve this?

In my solution I have two projects built from mostly the same files. Projects produce different outputs because of different target .NET framework versions and different conditional compilation symbols.

Now, when I invoke Find All References command, I get results for both projects. This basically duplicates each result.

I would like to get results for current project only, or at least for a one project only. I hope there is a way to narrow search area to the current project or there is a way to exclude some projects from the search area.

Is it possible to search for symbols in current project only? Is it possible to exclude projects from search area?

EDIT:

I use Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Resharper. Its "Find usages" option produces no duplicates.
Also resharper has "Find Usages Advanced" option that allow to narrow search scope to current project.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I have found to exclude projects from **'Find All References'** is to actually unload the unwanted project temporarily, i.e. right-click on project -> Unload Project. (For C/C++ projects you then also have to right click project -> Rescan Solution to regenerate symbol data before searching.) You can then 'Reload Project' before building.

An alternative is to use custom component set searching instead:

- **In VS2010**: Goto Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find Symbol. Change the 'Look in' scope to be Custom Component Set (Find Symbol), and click the '...' to show the Edit Custom Component Set dialog.
- **In VS2013**: Goto View -> Object Browser. Change the Browse dropdown to show Custom Component Set, and click '...' to show the Edit Custom Component Set dialog.
- In the custom component set dialog click the 'Projects' tab and Add just the project you want. This custom component set is stored with the solution so you only have to set this up once.

[image: Edit Custom Component Set Dialog]

Comment: I can not find Projects tab. When I click `...` next to text field below `Look In:` I only see `Choose search folders` dialog and the dialog allows to choose folders only. Is it because I use Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 3?

Comment: Hi I think you clicked Find in files by mistake. I checked VS2013 and Find Symbol is not on the menu by default so you may not see it. You can add Find Symbol using menu customisation, or you can use the object browser instead, I added new instructions above.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can find the tab.

Comment: in my solution file i have serveral test projects who reference my methods. If i wanna check my control flow/ method usage, these results are not helpful. Unloading the projects helps here (VS 2019). Thanks a lot!